Big Objects not being inserted from Batch class
I wrote a scheduled batch class that takes old EmailMessages, deletes them, and recreates them as "EmailMessageArchive__B" big objects, something custom I wrote to free up a lot of space in our org. I tried this batch on singular records in my sandbox and everything worked exactly as I expected.
Now I am trying to do it on batch sizes of 500 and I am seeing odd behavior.
I re-query my # of EmailMessages with SOQL and I see that after running the batch, the number went down 500, as expected - 500 got deleted.
Then I re-query the # of EmailMessageArchived__b in my org, and the number only goes up by a random amount, like 84. This happens every single time I run it.
After doing most of the object creation, this is how I end my execute() method:
    if(newEmailMessages.size() > 0)
    {
        List<Database.SaveResult> results = Database.insertImmediate(newEmailMessages);
        system.debug(results.size());
        for(Database.SaveResult sr : results)
        {
            if(sr.isSuccess())
            {
              System.debug('Successfully inserted email. ID: ' + sr.getId());    
            }
            else
            {
                for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                    System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                    System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                    System.debug('Email fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                }    
            }

        }
    }
    if(emailsToDelete.size() > 0)
    {
        delete emailsToDelete;
    }        

The debug message confirms to me that the SIZE of the "results" list is 500. So every one of the 500 new EmailMessageArchive__B records did make it through. I then check my logs and I see 500 lines of the "Sucessfully inserted email" message. So I am definitely queueing up all 500 EmailMessageArchive__B records for insert. And I am getting 0 validation errors on any of them. So why on earth are only a few of them actually getting inserted and coming up in my SOQL query?!
Has anyone who has worked with Big Objects ever encountered this problem? Thanks

How is the Index of your Big Object defined? Have you made sure there can be no duplicates based on your emails? "Reinserting a record with the same index but different data results in behavior similar to an upsert operation."
